# Access an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Hi I am reading in a text file and storing the content in an array called abbreviations. I have done a for loop to check if the a given string is in the array and if so I want to assign  the next element to an variable.

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Hass 2\\Dropbox\\work\\Java\\Assessment3\\abbreviations.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (s.hasNext()) {
      String line = s.next();
      String[] lineSplit = line.split(","); //split into two tokens
      list.add(lineSplit[0]); //word
      list.add(lineSplit[1]); //number
}

String [] abbreviations = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
s.close();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abbreviations));
String test = "hello";
String abbreviatedWord = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < abbreviations.length; i++) {

            if(test.equals(abbreviations[i])) {
                //assign word to the abbreviated word
                abbreviatedWord = abbreviations[i+1];

        } else {
          abbreviatedWord = test;
        }
      }
        System.out.println(abbreviatedWord);
    }
```

When I compile and run the program I get the output as hello (which exist in the text file) and not the next element along.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: show some of your output

Comment: Also can you show us 3 sample lines in your text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break the for loop after finding the word "hello".

```
 for(int i = 0; i < abbreviations.length; i++) {

    if(test.equals(abbreviations[i])) {
            //assign word to the abbreviated word
            abbreviatedWord = abbreviations[i+1]; //potential arrayoutofbound exception
            break;

    } else {
      abbreviatedWord = test;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, like others have suggested, you could use hashmap. It will be more efficient and also help you avoid the ArrayOutOfBound exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are not returning after assigning `abbreviatedWord` put a `return` or `break` statement in the if condition.

```
for(int i = 0; i < abbreviations.length; i++) {
            if(test.equals(abbreviations[i])) {
                //assign word to the abbreviated word
                abbreviatedWord = abbreviations[i+1]; //though this line will give you ArrayoutofBoundException
                return ;

        } else {
          abbreviatedWord = test;
        }
      }
```

Looks like you know about `Collections` so I would suggest to use `HashMap` in such condition. Here is the implementation of same logic

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FoudnNextWord{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Scanner s = new Scanner(
                new File(
                        "C:\\Users\\Hass 2\\Dropbox\\work\\Java\\Assessment3\\abbreviations.txt"));
        final Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            final String[] line = s.next().split(",");
            list.put(line[0], line[1]);
        }
        final String test = "hello";
        if (list.containsKey(test)) {
            System.out.println("The next word is: " + list.get(test));
        } else {
            System.out.println("The next word is " + test);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'for(i' loop will pass on all input elements.
When it passes on the 'good' one, it sets abbreviatedWord to the good value, but then it passes on 'bad' ones, and resets abbreviatedWord to test.

You can try:

```
String abbreviatedWord = test;
for(int i = 0; i < abbreviations.length; i++) {
  if(test.equals(abbreviations[i])) {
    //assign word to the abbreviated word
    abbreviatedWord = abbreviations[i+1];
  }
}
```

You should also consider using a hashmap, that will be **much** more efficient.

Comment: You can also break as proposed by Nikhil, it's not worth continuing in the loop once you found the result.